# Inverse Binary Feature

Tags: neural-network, feature-selection, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

I am feeding a binary value into my NN which represents whether the given example is a public holiday or not.

Is there a difference between assigning a 0 to public holidays and 1 to all other days or encoding it inversely?

If I am not mistaken, it should make no difference as the NN learns to assign corresponding weights/ bias anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does not matter how you encode your features. Remember that bias is there for a reason, think about a simple perceptron with this weight and a ReLu activation function:

- f(x) = b + wx = 1 - 1*x

If you have x = 1 then f(1) = 0, and no signal will pass. However, if you have a x = 0 then f(0) = 1 and we will have a signal flowing on our network. Therefore, your network will learn the appropriate parameters to classify your data correctly based on a loss function given.

I hope this helps.